# Missing BitBucket branch link in Jira Ticket

Tags: bitbucket, jira

I am able to see the development section and "Create Branch" link. I am also able to create branch from Jira using the link, but my new branch does not show up in the ticket. Still just says "Create Branch". The branch is actually created and I can verify that in BitBucket. Are there some settings that I miss?

Comment: I'm seeing an issue with this as well. I created a branch from the ticket - naming convention matches what's expected. The branch is not being picked up by development tools in JIRA. I use this feature all the time and normally it works, just not this one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your branch name should contain the Jira ticket code.

Eg, if your ticket was XY-1056, your branch should be "bugfix/XY-1056-my-fix" or something along those lines.

Comment: My ticket is DEV-13 and my branch is DEV-13-implement-additional-parameters-a

As created in Jira.

Comment: Yeah, so if you want a branch to appear under the ticket DEV-14, you'll need a branch with "DEV-14" in it. Alternatively, you can tag a commit in your DEV-13 branch with "DEV-14 something something" to have Jira track the commit instead.

Comment: Sorry, I mean DEV-13 is my ticket number.

Comment: Does your Jira have permissions for contacting BitBucket? (I'm not sure if the permissions for making a branch are the same for reading from BitBucket)

Comment: Jira can create branches. How would I check for reading permissions?

Comment: In capabilities in Jira development tools section it says: Create branches
create and view pull requests, view commits. Does it need to have create and view branches? How would I change that?

Comment: Hmm, in that case, I'm afraid I don't know. Sorry about that. You'd probably find better luck asking on the Jira help boards instead.